# How to show document rendered image pages with scroll and pinch zoom in Android

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview, pinchzoom

I have a pdf doc in a server which I get through a service as an array of images. Each image correspond to a PDF page rendered.

I would like to show all the images of the documentn in my App. The user should be able to scroll up un down the page images and zoom "pinching".

I achieved the scrolling functionality using a scrollview. However I don't find a good solution for setting the zoom through pinch gesture. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Sourab for your answer,

Finally I have used a WebView to perform the functionality. It's been a bit tricky but it has zooming and scrolling functionality out of the box

What I do is create a String that contains the images as follows:

```
String x= "<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0\"/><style type=\"text/css\">html, body {margin: 0;padding: 0;} img {border: none;}</style><head><body style=\"background: black;\"><table><tr><td align=\"center\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA....\"/></td></tr></table></body></html>";
```

Afterthat I load the WebView:

```
aWebView.loadData(x, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

A last trick to adjust the width of the content to the webView width:

```
aWebView.setInitialScale(30);
aWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

And to allow zoom:

```
aWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Loading images in a string is not very nice but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented pinch zoom in my old project by using TouchImageView created by MikeOrtiz

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Try it !